# esc button OS X needs to be released on every command

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard

In terminal I use <kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>  or <kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>  to jump through the words.

If I want 2x back I've to do <kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> twice. Otherwise I just start typing F or B in Terminal.

The modifier keys <kbd>ctrl</kbd> / <kbd>alt</kbd> /<kbd>cmd</kbd> work differently e.g. I can hit control and than hit AAA EEEE multiple times without a need to release control button. So go to end of line twice would be <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and this would work (don't mind the fact that this is pointless end of line is end of line)

Is there a way to achieve same with <kbd>esc</kbd> modifier?

Comment: esc is not a modifier but an actual key so you are doing esc then b not esc and b at the same time. alt + b is alt and b at the same time

Comment: @Mark so how do I make it work like a modifier? :)

Comment: You can't it is a key sending a character just like the key X

Comment: @Mark never mind I found solution, terminal `esc` can be remapped to `alt`

Comment: @SandroDzneladze In my opinion you can modify every key to behave like a modifier key (with Karabiner). Which editor do you use? E.g. in nano esc-b/f don't allow you to jump to the previous or the next word.

Comment: @klanomath question was about terminal, as for editor I use vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

selecting `Use option as meta key` allows alt/option to be used instead of esc.